# VMWare workstation 11 on Windows 10 with Radeon 290 dual screen bad performance

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, vmware-workstation, amd-radeon

I discovered a strange behavior in VMWare workstation since upgrading to Windows 10. My Radeon 290 goes to 2D clocks (300 MHz) and remains there. If I set a guest to full screen the desktop experience in that guest is horrendous (dragging windows around clips a lot and is really choppy).

If I run VLC in the background with rendering set to Direct2D, the Radeon clocks switch to 500-600 MHz and performance in the virtual machine is more acceptable.

Are there any workarounds for this?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried virtual machines yet but upgraded to win10 and also have a 290,
try to see if the problem happens else where because ive seen some strange behavior that I think are gpu related, when with just a few tabs open sometimes the fan ramps up to 70ish percent, sometimes when chrome is maxed out on my second monitor it just freezes, i can control the window but cant see the changes until I resize it. I upgraded to the lastest beta drivers and have not noticed any problems